# How to Edit Main Sql in Crystal Report

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-xi

I would like to know **how to edit Main Sql in Crystal Report**.
I am using **cyrstal report 7** and I'm just beginner in report and also don't know much about CR7.
You know CR7 is really old but in my company, some reports are still using cr7.

The problem is I want to add **TOP 1** in main sql.
MAIN SQL - `SELECT A.ID,A.CLASS,A.NAME,....`
I want to change above example code as follow:
MAIN SQL - `SELECT TOP 1 A.ID,A.CLASS,A.NAME,....`

Help me please. Any idea, suggestion?

Comment: go to database expert and edit

Comment: yes bro but I didn't see database expert in CR7. I see is report expert and section expert and link expert.

Answer (score 1):

Try the link below (it provides all kinds of information about cr7):
http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_reports_tutorials.htm

Comment: Specifically this one: http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_step_by_step.htm

Comment: I doubt that you had a look at it.Start with Sample Database and tables for Crystal Reports tutorials and then Step by Step help for creating a simple Crystal Reports in VB.NET. The following might also be helpfull: https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/guides/afn/crystal_reports_7_users_guide.pdf

Comment: The above mentioned link is a comprehensive guide to CR7 and about 6.5mb big 400+ pages.Look under the Database Menu

Comment: Thanks @Danie Schoeman.
I will check but somehow I can solve the case what i asked.